Reading a BMP file and rotating it
for a few weeks now I've been struggling with creating a function in C that could rotate BMP files 90 degrees clockwise or counter-clockwise. No matter what I do or how I read/change the header nothing about it seems to work, I've even tried getting AI to generate the code but alas nothing seems to work, I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if there's something wrong with my config or what. If there's something I'm missing or if there's an easier way to do this please let me know
Thank you.
EDIT: removed the second question here, will ask later, srry about that
(sorry, it's in spanish)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short  bm;       //tipo de fichero "BM"
    unsigned int    tam;      //tamanyo
    unsigned short  res1;     //reservado
    unsigned short  res2;     //reservado
    unsigned int    inicio;   //inicio datos de imagen
    unsigned int    head;     //tamanyo de la cabecera del bitmap
    unsigned int    x;        //ancho en pixeles
    unsigned int    y;        //alto en pixeles
    unsigned short  planes;   //numero de planos
    unsigned short  tam_pun;  //tamanyo de cada punto
    unsigned int    comp;     //compresion
    unsigned int    img;      //tamanyo imagen
    unsigned int    r_hor;    //resolucion horizontal
    unsigned int    r_ver;    //resolucion vertical
    unsigned int    t_color;  //tamanyo tabla de color
    unsigned int    impor;    //contador de colores importantes
}bmpHeader;

void rotar(FILE *f, int rotar) {
    bmpHeader header;
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned char *data_rot;
    int i, j, k;

    // Leer la cabecera del BMP
    fread(&header, sizeof(bmpHeader), 1, f);

    // Asignar memoria para los datos de la imagen
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc(header.img);
    data_rot = (unsigned char *)malloc(header.img);

    // Leer los datos de la imagen
    fread(data, header.img, 1, f);

    // Rotar la imagen
    if (rotar == 0) {
        // Rotar 90 grados a la derecha
        for (i = 0; i < header.x; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < header.y; j++) {
                k = (header.x - i - 1) * header.y + j;
                data_rot[k] = data[i * header.y + j];
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Rotar 90 grados a la izquierda
        for (i = 0; i < header.x; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < header.y; j++) {
                k = i * header.y + (header.y - j - 1);
                data_rot[k] = data[i * header.y + j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Escribir la cabecera del BMP
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(bmpHeader), 1, f);

    // Escribir los datos de la imagen
    fwrite(data_rot, header.img, 1, f);

    // Liberar la memoria
    free(data);
    free(data_rot);
}


Please open a separate question for your 2nd question, and then remove it from this question.  Thank you and welcome to SO. -- Please disregard in light of comment from @AndreasWenzel

@gregspears: I believe interpreting the padding bytes properly is a requirement for solving the main problem, so I believe it makes sense to combine both questions into one, even if OP formulated the question in such a way as if both issues were not directly related.

You appear to be assuming that the actual pixel data appears directly after the header. This may be the case. However, depending on the file format (which is specified in the header), there may also be palette information beforehand. What is the value of the biCompression field in the BITMAPINFOHEADER structure? I believe this field should correspond to the comp field in your structure.

You also appear to be assuming that every pixel consists of 8 bits. As far as I know, this is only likely to be true if you are using a palette instead of storing the pixel information in RGB format. This is another reason why we need to know the value of the biCompression field mentioned in my previous comment. If it has the value 0, then you are using uncompressed RGB, which would mean that every pixel has 3 bytes, not 1 byte.

Did you create the bmpHeader structure yourself? If so, then I suggest that you use uint16_t (requires #include <stdint.h>) instead of unsigned short and uint32_t instead of unsigned int, because an int is not guaranteed to have a size of 4 bytes on all platforms, whereas a uint32_t is guaranteed to have the same size on all platforms.

In the definition of your structure bmpHeader, x and y have the wrong type. It should be signed int, not unsigned int. This is important, because bitmaps can have a negative height. A bitmap with a negative height indicates a top-down bitmap (the top row is stored first), whereas a bitmap with a positive height indicates a bottom-up bitmap (the bottom row is stored first). You should check whether the height is positive or negative, to determine what type of bitmap you are dealing with.

One issue with BMP files is that all of the 4-byte values in the header are misaligned due to the two byte "BM" magic at the beginning of the file.  Thus it is usually better to remove that from your 'bmpHeader' struct and read it separately.
bmpHeader header;
uint16_t magic;

if (fread(magic, 1, sizeof(magic), f) != sizeof(magic) || magic != 0x4d42 ||
    fread(&header, 1, sizeof(header), f) != sizeof(header)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading bmp header");
    exit(1);
}

That way you don't need to worry about alignment or padding in the header.  Checking the magic number as a uint16_t rather than 2 chars will also check the byte ordering to ensure it is proper for your machine -- if it is 0x424d you need to byteswap everything.
You should also always check the return value of your fread calls!

An alternative would be to tell the compiler to have no padding inside the structure, for example by using __attribute__((__packed__)) on gcc/clang or #pragma pack(1) on MSVC.

@AndreasWenzel: yes, but there's no reliable/portable way of doing that -- it depends on the compiler and the system as to whether it will even work or cause misaligned traps.

Use a library, see http://cimg.eu/

I am loathe to recommend any specific library to read and write BMP files (but I’m gonna). You should save yourself some grief and use one. Google found me cbmp, which looks decent. If you want to use C++, then EasyBMP is the choice you want to make. Of course, you could go loco and use a bigger library like OpenImageIO, but that is total overkill for your needs.
In any case, once you have a library loading and saving image data for you, you can stop worrying about things like stride and whatnot. Just perform the rotate.
If you wish to stick to loading and saving it yourself
...then you should put the effort into loading the image data into a structure that simply represents packed 32-bit ARGB pixel data. This again frees you from having to deal with things like pixel format and row stride when modifying the image proper.
In other words, separate tasks into simpler tasks, and don’t let the complexities of one task creep into unrelated tasks.

If you don't want to use an existing library, you should structure your code like a library -- have separate routines for load/store a bitmap and rotate a bitmap, and have clean interfaces for each, so main becomes trivial with just 3 calls + error checking and reporting.

The size of the rotated image may not match the size of the original. Also you use header.img (biSizeImage) value in your code, but it CAN BE 0 for uncompressed RGB bitmaps.
I've tweaked your code to make it work for all uncompressed formats. Note that all structures must be byte-aligned (see PACK macro).
#include <memory.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRY do { jmp_buf ex_buf__; if (!setjmp(ex_buf__)) {
#define CATCH } else {
#define ETRY }} while(0)
#define THROW longjmp(ex_buf__, 1)

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PACK(__decl__) __decl__ __attribute__((packed))
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define PACK(__decl__) __pragma(pack(push, 1)) __decl__ __pragma(pack(pop))
#endif

PACK(typedef struct {
    unsigned short bfType;
    unsigned int   bfSize;
    unsigned short bfReserved1;
    unsigned short bfReserved2;
    unsigned int   bfOffBits;
}) BITMAPFILEHEADER;

PACK(typedef struct {
    unsigned int   biSize;
    int            biWidth;
    int            biHeight;
    unsigned short biPlanes;
    unsigned short biBitCount;
    unsigned int   biCompression;
    unsigned int   biSizeImage;
    int            biXPelsPerMeter;
    int            biYPelsPerMeter;
    unsigned int   biClrUsed;
    unsigned int   biClrImportant;
 }) BITMAPINFOHEADER;

PACK(typedef struct {
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bhFile;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bhInfo;
}) BITMAPHEADER;

PACK(typedef struct {
    unsigned char rgbBlue;
    unsigned char rgbGreen;
    unsigned char rgbRed;
    unsigned char rgbReserved;
}) RGBQUAD;

char const* const msgs[] = {
    "Ok",
    "Error reading the sorce file",
    "Unknown bmp file format",
    "Error creating the destination file"
};

int rotate(FILE* src_f, FILE* dst_f, int direction);
void rotate_file(FILE* src_f, char const* dst_file_name, int direction);

int main() {

    char const* src_file_name = "original.bmp";

    FILE* src_f = fopen(src_file_name, "rb");
    if (src_f) {
        rotate_file(src_f, "right_rotated.bmp", 0);
        rotate_file(src_f, "left_rotated.bmp",  1);
        fclose(src_f);
    } else {
        printf("%s: %s\n", src_file_name, msgs[1]);
    }
}

void rotate_file(FILE* src_f, char const* dst_file_name, int direction) {

    int result = 3;

    FILE* dst_f = fopen(dst_file_name, "wb");
    if (dst_f) {
        result = rotate(src_f, dst_f, direction);
        fclose(dst_f);
    }

    printf("%s: %s\n", dst_file_name, msgs[result]);
}

int get_stride(BITMAPINFOHEADER* bhInfo) {
    return (((bhInfo->biWidth * bhInfo->biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3;
}

int sgn(int val) {
    return (0 < val) - (val < 0);
}

int rotate(FILE* src_f, FILE* dst_f, int direction) {

    BITMAPHEADER src_header;
    BITMAPHEADER dst_header;
    RGBQUAD* palette = NULL;
    unsigned char* src_data = NULL;
    unsigned char* dst_data = NULL;

    int result = 1;

    TRY {
        // Get actual source file size
        fseek(src_f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int src_file_size = ftell(src_f);
        fseek(src_f, 0, SEEK_SET);

        // Read the BMP header
        if (fread(&src_header, sizeof(BITMAPHEADER), 1, src_f) != 1) THROW;

        result = 2;

        if (src_header.bhFile.bfType   != 0x4d42 ||
            src_header.bhInfo.biWidth  <=  0 ||
            src_header.bhInfo.biHeight ==  0 ||
            src_header.bhInfo.biSize   != 40) THROW;

        memcpy(&dst_header, &src_header, sizeof(BITMAPHEADER));

        // Positive height: the bitmap is a bottom - up
        // Negative height: the bitmap is a top - down
        int src_height = abs(src_header.bhInfo.biHeight);
        int dst_height = src_header.bhInfo.biWidth;
        int dy = sgn(src_header.bhInfo.biHeight);
        dst_header.bhInfo.biWidth  = src_height;
        dst_header.bhInfo.biHeight = dst_height * dy;
        dst_header.bhInfo.biXPelsPerMeter = src_header.bhInfo.biYPelsPerMeter;
        dst_header.bhInfo.biYPelsPerMeter = src_header.bhInfo.biXPelsPerMeter;

        int src_stride = get_stride(&src_header.bhInfo);
        int dst_stride = get_stride(&dst_header.bhInfo);

        int src_map_size = src_stride * src_height;
        int dst_map_size = dst_stride * dst_height;

        int palette_size = src_header.bhFile.bfOffBits - sizeof(BITMAPHEADER);
        if (palette_size < sizeof(RGBQUAD) * src_header.bhInfo.biClrUsed) THROW;

        if (src_file_size < sizeof(BITMAPHEADER) + palette_size + src_map_size) THROW;
        int dst_file_Size = sizeof(BITMAPHEADER) + palette_size + dst_map_size;

        dst_header.bhFile.bfSize      = dst_file_Size;
        dst_header.bhInfo.biSizeImage = dst_map_size;

        result = 1;
        
        if (palette_size) {
            if (!(palette = (RGBQUAD*)malloc(palette_size))) THROW;
            if (fread(palette, palette_size, 1, src_f) != 1) THROW;
        }

        if (!(src_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(src_map_size))) THROW;
        if (fread(src_data, src_map_size, 1, src_f) != 1) THROW;

        result = 3;

        // Zero empty spaces
        if (!(dst_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(dst_map_size))) THROW;
        memset(dst_data, 0, dst_map_size);

        switch (src_header.bhInfo.biBitCount) {

        case 1:

            if (direction == dy < 0) {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CW (right)
                int dst_y_max = dst_height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        int k = (dst_y_max - i) * dst_stride + (j >> 3);
                        if (src_data[(i >> 3) + j * src_stride] & (0x80 >> (i & 7)))
                            dst_data[k] |= (0x80 >> (j & 7));
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CCW (left)
                int dst_x_max = dst_header.bhInfo.biWidth - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        int k = i * dst_stride + ((dst_x_max - j) >> 3);
                        if (src_data[(i >> 3) + j * src_stride] & (0x80 >> (i & 7)))
                            dst_data[k] |= (0x80 >> ((dst_x_max - j) & 7));
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 4:

            if (direction == dy < 0) {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CW (right)
                int dst_y_max = dst_height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        int k = (dst_y_max - i) * dst_stride + (j >> 1);
                        unsigned char m = i & 1
                            ? src_data[(i >> 1) + j * src_stride] & 0x0F
                            : src_data[(i >> 1) + j * src_stride] >> 4;
                        dst_data[k] |= (j & 1) ? m : m << 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CCW (left)
                int dst_x_max = dst_header.bhInfo.biWidth - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        int k = i * dst_stride + ((dst_x_max - j) >> 1);
                        unsigned char m = i & 1
                            ? src_data[(i >> 1) + j * src_stride] & 0x0F
                            : src_data[(i >> 1) + j * src_stride] >> 4;
                        dst_data[k] |= ((dst_x_max - j) & 1) ? m : m << 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case  8:
        case 16:
        case 24:
        case 32:

            int bpp = src_header.bhInfo.biBitCount >> 3;
            if (direction == dy < 0) {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CW (right)
                int dst_y_max = dst_height - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        for (int b = 0; b < bpp; b++) {
                            int k = (dst_y_max - i) * dst_stride + j * bpp + b;
                            dst_data[k] = src_data[i * bpp + j * src_stride + b];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Rotate 90 degrees CCW (left)
                int dst_x_max = dst_header.bhInfo.biWidth - 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < src_header.bhInfo.biWidth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < src_height; j++) {
                        for (int b = 0; b < bpp; b++) {
                            int k = i * dst_stride + (dst_x_max - j) * bpp + b;
                            dst_data[k] = src_data[i * bpp + j * src_stride + b];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    
        if (fwrite(&dst_header, sizeof(BITMAPHEADER), 1, dst_f) != 1) THROW;

        if (palette_size) {
            if (fwrite(palette, palette_size, 1, dst_f) != 1) THROW;
        }

        if (fwrite(dst_data, dst_map_size, 1, dst_f) != 1) THROW;

        result = 0;
    }

    CATCH {
    }

    ETRY;

    // Liberar la memoria
    if (palette) free(palette);
    if (src_data) free(src_data);
    if (dst_data) free(dst_data);

    return result;
}


On the compilers gcc/clang, the option for having no padding bytes is __attribute__((__packed__)).

This code will not work for bitmaps which have a negative height (to indicate a top-down bitmap). See my comment to the question for further information.

Andreas Wenzel, I sprinkle ashes on my head, I forgot about the negative height. The code has already been fixed.
